# Locate my "Uploaded YouTube Videos" that have NO Playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I've uploaded videos to YouTube. Most of them I have organized by playlists, but I'm sure I have missed cataloging some.

How can I locate all of my videos that don't belong to any playlist, so that I can add them to playlists?